# Types for dependency of dependency in Dev Env not building

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependencies, npm-install, npm-build

I understand variations of this question have been asked six ways to Sunday, but none of the answers on those questions are fixing my issue.

I have created package A. Its build is included in a dist folder and the package is loaded to npm.

I have created package B, in which package A is a dependency. Package B has also built properly and the package is loaded to npm. Note: Package A includes dev packs for the typings of things like express, mongoose etc. When installed and then built within B, there are no errors.

I have created package C in which A and B are dependencies. After install, this package will NOT build. The errors indicate missings types for dependencies of A (express, mongoose, etc).

I have ensured that there is version consistency between A, B and C. Nope. Done a dev only install in C. Nope. Added the typings of A as dev packs in C, and installed, and dev-only installed. Nope. Recreated C from scratch then installed then attempted to build. Nope.

Again, B also uses A and builds properly with no errors abt the typings from A. I'm at a complete loss as to what is wrong. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thx all